# Use jsdoc on js with flow type annotations

Tags: javascript, jsdoc, flowtype

When trying to process js sources with flow type annotations the jsdoc parser failes to understand the enhanced syntax! Is there a way to use jsdoc in js sources that have been enhanced with flow type annotations or what is the recommended way to generate documentation from type annotated js?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use babel with [strip-flow-types](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-transform-flow-strip-types) transform and use [jsdoc-babel](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsdoc-babel).

First, you need to install babel and related packages and jsdoc-babel on top of jsdoc. Then, create a `jsdoc-conf.json` file in your root directory containing something like this:

```
{
    "plugins": ["node_modules/jsdoc-babel"],
    "babel": {
        "presets": ["react"],
        "plugins": ["transform-react-jsx", "transform-flow-strip-types"]
    }
}
```

Usage: `jsdoc -c jsdoc-conf.json`

You can use any valid babel setup with jsdoc-babel under "babel" that is applied in addition to your `.babelrc` file.  e.g. presets for ES2015 or other babel plugins. Hope this helps!

Comment: This answer could be improved by providing a working code example. Welcome to stackoverflow by the way!

Answer (score 7):

Just started using [documentation.js](https://github.com/documentationjs/documentation). Supports JSdoc and flow out of the box.