# how to write parameter description for flow and documentation

Tags: documentation, flowtype

how to write parameter description for flow and documentation

I tried a variety of methods, the currently feasible way can only work with jsdoc

```
export default class MyClass {
  /**
   * @param priority description
   */
  static add(
    priority: number, 
    handler: Handler
  ): MyClassAdd {
    return {
      priority,
      handler
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear to me exactly what the problem is, but I have two guesses: either JSDoc is not working because it is not able to parse code with Flow type annotations, or you are trying to find a way to combine Flow and JSDoc annotations so you do not have to write them twice. I will give you three possible solutions.

If the problem is that JSDoc is giving parse errors then you need to either pre-process the code to remove Flow type annotations before running JSDoc, or move the Flow annotations into comments. You can follow the instructions in this answer to add a pre-processing step:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/39364639/103017

Or you can hide the Flow annotations in comments using this syntax:

```
export default class MyClass {
  /**
   * @param priority description
   */
  static add(
    priority/*: number */, 
    handler/*: Handler */
  )/*: MyClassAdd */ {
    return {
      priority,
      handler
    }
  }
}
```

If you are trying to avoid writing two sets of annotations you could try using [flow-jsdoc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/flow-jsdoc) which generates Flow annotations from JSDoc annotations.